# Apple Room Key software/hardware documentation missing

Tags: iphone, wallet, nfc

[Some hotels have the Apple Room Key feature](https://youtu.be/ISxnUqb5_8Y) where you can unlock your door room and elevator according to your booking details with Wallet and NFC.

Us developpers, have the possibility to create passes, sometimes NFC passes with Apple special NFC certification that [we can obtain here](https://developer.apple.com/contact/passkit/).

However, I did not find any documentation about a "room key" feature.

I do believe then, that this feature is quite exclusive like the car key feature, but the car key feature is clearly made and stated to be developped with car manufacturers. Whereas this room key feature could not only benefit all sorts of hotels but also company offices and is mentioned nowhere on Apple's website (correct me if I'm wrong please).

The equivalent feature is [the home key announced at the WWDC21](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPTiVcKwdLk). It is well documented but limited to HomeKit capabilities and compatible devices.

Does someone know anything about this or was more lucky than me searching for this topic?

Answer (score 2):

Currently you need to partner with Apple in order to be able to take advantage of the Room Key feature. I imagine that in the future, they will make that more broadly available.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with partner? You mean a program we can publicly apply to like MFi? Or just to be close and in contact with Apple?